# Give control back to the first page after Server.execute()

Tags: asp.net

I have a registration.aspx page. After entering all the information, user has to press the register button, which will add it to the DB. After that it shows a message that says "registered successfully".

To do this I created a separate web form to display the success message. So after the process happens successfully I simply call this separate .aspx file by using

```
Server.Execute("~/AlertMsg/ValidationMsg.aspx");
```

So everything is fine. The user can see a beautiful box at the top of the page. But the problem is after executing the 2nd page (ValidationMsg.aspx) inside the 1st page, control goes to the 2nd page. Because of that, if I click a dropdown or button in my 1st page (that has autopostback enabled), my page only shows the validation window.

What I wanted to do is to take control back to the 1st page after executing the  `server.execute`. What should I do? Is there any good way to do this? I don't want to use JavaScript.

Below green color box is my separate web form.

**Image 1:**
[image: http://postimg.org/image/c2oh1t6w3/]

**Image 2 (after registering):**
[image: http://postimg.org/image/e3f0ayrnf/]

Comment: Is there is neccessary to show a confirmation message in second page. you can also show attractive message in same page as well.like in labels.

Comment: Of course I can. but think this alert boxes are like common boxes. So they were in a one page. All I am doing is just calling the Alert box with message that I want to display when ever I want. So I have to design only one source If later I need to redesign the alert boxes. seems like no way right?